# Retorno vacio al comparar 2 contadores (count) de 2 atributos en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estaba practicando con la base de datos llamado "Northwind" y al comparar 2 atributos me retorna vacio,
lo que quiero intentar hacer es mostrar el nombre del departamento y la cantidad de empleados asociados, para todos los departamentos que tengan la de cantidad de trabajadores menor a la cantidad del departamento ‘IT_PROG’.

El problema es que al comparar los contadores de empleados con el contador del job_id, me aparecen las tablas vacias

```
select d.department_name as Departamento, count(e.employee_id) as Total_Empleados
from employees as e
join departments as d on d.department_id = e.department_id
group by department_name
having count(e.employee_id) < count(e.job_id='it_prog');
```

En cambio, cuando coloco:

```
having count(e.employee_id) < 5; /*Siendo count(e.job_id='it_prog') = 5*/
```

Me imprime el resultado que quiero, ¿por qué pasa esto?

Comment: ¿Esta función `count(e.job_id='it_prog');` por si sola que te devuelve?

Answer (score 1):

```
select d.department_name as Departamento, count(e.employee_id) as Total_Empleados
from employees as e
join departments as d on d.department_id = e.department_id
group by department_name
having count(e.employee_id) < (select count(e.employee_id)
from employees as e     
join departments as d on d.department_id = e.department_id
where d.nombreDepartamento = 'it_prog'
group by department_name)
```

En la **cláusula having** se hace una subconsulta que cuenta los empleados del departamento **'it_prog'**, esta subconsulta devuelve un valor que va a ser el usado para comparar con tu consulta original.

Comment: Un poco mala la sintaxis, pero sirvió para entender la idea, el código final me quedó así:

    select d.department_name as Departamento, count(e.employee_id) as 
    Total_Empleados
    from employees as e
    join departments as d on d.department_id = e.department_id
    group by department_name
    having count(e.employee_id) < (select count(e.job_id) from employees as e
    where e.job_id='it_prog'
    group by department_name)

Comment: ok, lo importante es que te sirva y puedas utilizarla y mejorarla si lo deseas, suerte